# IProgress<T> in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, progress-bar

Is there some older .NET 4.0 equivalent of interface or class of [IProgress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298(v=vs.110).aspx) (which is available only from .NET 4.5) which can be used for sending progress from task to UI?

Or should I write my own class/interface for it?

Comment: I think that you should to define you own interface, just make sure that it contains same members like IProgress from net 4.5/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are really two parts to `IProgress<T>`: the interface itself, and the provided implementation, `Progress<T>`. Technically, the interface doesn't even require cross-thread support, though of course that's how it's used in practice.

The interface, you could just copy verbatim from the documentation for .NET 4.5. It's just a declaration. But for it to be useful, you'll want to implement it as well. For that, you'll need to use `SynchronizationContext` to handle the cross-thread invocation of the `ProgressChanged` event or the handler provided to the `Progress<T>` constructor. You could write the whole thing yourself, but IMHO it's reasonable to just copy/paste from the .NET source code: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/progress.cs,d23df0450d3fd0d6

It's a relatively simple class, and wouldn't be hard to reimplement, but there shouldn't be anything about the actual .NET implementation that requires other 4.5 features, so copy/paste from the source should work fine.

That said, note that the equivalent *functionality* is in fact available in earlier versions of .NET, in the form of the `BackgroundWorker` class. This combines both the asynchronous execution that is typically used alongside `IProgress<T>` with the `ProgressChanged` event that allows the asynchronous operation to report progress. Since there's only one .NET version before 4.5 that also includes the TPL support that is typically used with `IProgress<T>`, using `BackgroundWorker` probably makes more sense in the context of pre-4.5 legacy code.